# Parse DayTime from 2 formats

Tags: c#

I want to parse the date a user puts in. He is allowed to either use the format DD.MM.YYYY or DDMMYYYY.

Unfortunately everything I tried hasn´t worked

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
string[] dateFormat = new string[] { "dd.mm.yyyy", "ddmmyyyy" };

string userInput = "30.10.2000" // or "30102000"

date = DateTime.ParseExact(date, dateFormat, null);
```

"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" is the exception. I am from Austria but can´t find a culture code that is working.
Thanks

Comment: you can use `TryParseExact`. It returns true, if the string is correct. And i think the method is case sensitive. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: A simple *typo*; it should be `"dd.MM.yyyy", "ddMMyyyy"` since `m` stands for *minutes*, not *months*

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.MinValue;
string[] dateFormats = { "dd.MM.yyyy", "ddMMyyyy" };
string userInput = "30.10.2000"; // or "30102000"

bool isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(userInput, dateFormats, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);

Console.WriteLine($"{date:O}"); // prints date in ISO format
```

If `date` is parsed correctly then `isValid` will be set to `true`.

Comment: There's an overload of  `DateTime.TryParseExact` that takes an array of formats to try, so the Linq here is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don´t know why I took over 3 hours and still failed to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

It is `yyyy` for 4 digit years and `dd` for 2 digit days. It is case-sensitive. You also neglected to pass the `dateFormat` array into `ParseExact`, so it will attempt to only do that single format.

Comment: @d0neall you still have the upper-case formats in your example.

Comment: sorry overlooked that